# How can i minus value from 2 columns and then apply max function in sequelizejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get a max record after minus 2 columns value. I am able to make that query on phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT `storage_id`, `host` FROM `storages` 
WHERE size - used = (SELECT MAX(size - used) FROM `storages`
```

but struggling on sequelizejs. Any help?

**Updated:**

I have updated my query and now it's easier than previous.

```
SELECT `storage_id`, `host`, size - used AS free FROM `storages` ORDER BY free DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found [Sequelize.literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral) which helped me achieve this in Sequelize.

```
Storage.findOne({
    attributes: ['storage_id', 'host', [Sequelize.literal('size - used'), 'free']],
    order: 'free DESC'
  })
```